# Using javascript/jQuery to access html elements that have ids/attributes dynamically generated with angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Is there a way in jQuery/javascript to select an html element with an id or other attribute dynamically generated by AngularJS?

For example, I have a dropdown with an id created using this angular code:

```
ng-attr-id="{{'type-'+($index+1}}"
```

I would like to get the value of an element with id "type-2". But the javascript is not finding an element with id 'type-2" on the same page.

All advice appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not assign it an `ng-model` and get the value via Angular... it's generally frowned upon to mix Angular and jQuery, as it typically creates problems.

Comment: need to show more code and explain what you want to do.  You probably don't even need an ID

Comment: And where is your JS/jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have are missing a ')' after `$index + 1`

change this code to

```
ng-attr-id="{{'type-'+($index+1)}}"
```

and then try:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   alert($("#type-2").html());
});
```